# Mobile ads - Location-based product promotion (Givted) - Patent Application - PRIOR ART REQUEST

Tags: prior-art-request, pre-grant, online-advertising, us20130173389, geo-target

**AN OVERBROAD PATENT ON sending product specials or lists of products to a user's cellphone based on user location** - This application from [Givted, Inc.](http://www.givted.com) seeks to patent the idea of...sending product promotion to user based on location! 10 minutes of your time can help narrow US patent applications before they become patents.  [Follow @askpatents](https://twitter.com/AskPatents) on twitter to help.

**QUESTION** - Have you seen anything that was **published before 12/30/2011** that discusses:

> - Using user's location (and possibly user's fitness data) to send product specials to user's cell phone

If so, please submit evidence of prior art as an answer to this question. We welcome multiple answers from the same individual.

**EXTRA CREDIT** - A reference to anything that meets all of the criteria to the question above AND ALSO takes into account **user fitness data** or relates to **sporting goods**

Note: We wish all the best to the startup company Givted behind this patent, but...**should this company go bankrupt this is the sort of patent which ends up in the hands of a patent troll.**

**TITLE: location-based customization and product promotion**

**Summary**:  [Translated from Legalese into English] A retail systems that sends a list of specials to a user's phone based on the location of the user or attendance of the user at an event or user's fitness data.

- **Publication Number**: [US20130173389 A1](https://www.google.com/patents/US20130173389?dq=US20130173389A1)
- **Application Number**: US 13/340,870
- **Assignee**: Givted, Inc.
- **Prior Art Date**: Seeking prior Art **predating** 12/30/2011
- **Open for Challenge at USPTO:** Open through 12/31/2013
- **Link to Google Prior Art Search** - ["Find Prior Art"](https://www.google.com/patents/related/US20130173389)

**Claim 1** requires each and every step below:

> A method comprising:
>
> 1. retrieving user information from a device;
> 2. determining a location of a user based on the retrieved user information;
> 3. compiling a list of available specials based on the location of the user;
> 4. transmitting the list of available specials to the device; and
> 5. transmitting a collection of products to the device.

In English this is pretty self-explanatory:

> A method comprising:
>
> 1. retrieving user information from a device;
> 2. determining a location of a user based on the retrieved user information;
> 3. compiling a list of available specials based on the location of the user;
> 4. transmitting the list of available specials to the device; and
> 5. transmitting a collection of products to the device.

Good prior art would be evidence of a system that did each and every one of these steps prior to 12/30/2011

You're probably aware of ten pieces of art that meet this criteria already... separately, the applicant is claiming combining **user fitness data** with location to provide offers to users

---

**"Sending product promotions to user based on location from the Applicant"**

[image]

---

*What is good prior art? Please see our [FAQ](https://patents.stackexchange.com/faq#prior-art).*

*Want to help? Please vote or comment on submissions below. We welcome you to [post your own request for prior art](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prior-art-request+pre-grant) on other questionable US Patent Applications.*

---

Answer (score 1):

FourSquare has a "Specials" feature, which will display businesses offering discounts near you on a map. It was discussed in this press release on 3/9/11: http://blog.foursquare.com/2011/03/09/a-whole-new-world-of-specials/

Regarding sporting goods, the post also specifically mention Sports Authority running a special through the program.

Answer (score 1):

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.97.1679&rep=rep1&type=pdf

This document, which dates back to June of 2004 describes a method of using Bluetooth sensors to find a users location and send ads based on that information. The figure below is taken from the document linked above.

[image: B-MAD figure]